# How to find all rows that have all another column values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables like these:

```
Tb1
------------
col
1
2
3

Tb2
-----------
id name Tb1_col
1   a    1
2   a    2
3   b    1
4   a    3
```

Now I want to fetch all `name` values from `Tb2` that have all `col` values from `Tb1`.
For this example I just expect `a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to `JOIN` Tb2 to Tb1 on `Tb1_col` and check that the number of distinct values for a given `name` is the same as the number of rows in `Tb1`:

```
SELECT Tb2.name
FROM Tb2
JOIN Tb1 ON Tb1.col = Tb2.Tb1_col
GROUP BY Tb2.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Tb2.Tb1_col) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tb1)
```

Output

```
a
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=8df21b43c40e84ddf74f61a327d02a60)

Answer (score 0):

Not very elegant solution, but....

```
SELECT distinct name from Tb2 as t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT t2.col, t3.id
                  FROM Tb1 as t2 LEFT JOIN Tb2 as t3 ON t3.Tb1_col = t2.col
                                                     AND t3.name = t1.name
                  WHERE t3.id IS NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

If `tb1_col` is defined as a foreign key (meaning that all values are valid references), then Nick's answer can be simplified:

```
SELECT Tb2.name
FROM Tb2
GROUP BY Tb2.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Tb2.Tb1_col) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tb1)
```

If `tb1_col` never duplicates for a given name, then using:

```
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tb1)
```

should be even more efficient.